# I have to send the content of a list to a string

Tags: python, list

I have to send the content of a list to a single string.

I've tried using a loop, but only could print the result:

```
for item in output_list:
   for line in item['output'].split('\n'):
      print(line)
```

## that is the list

```
            output_list = 
            {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "result": [
                {},
                {
                "tablesLastChangeTime": 1483721367.4560423,
                "tablesAgeOuts": 0,
                "tablesInserts": 3,
                "lldpNeighbors": [
                    {
                    "ttl": 120,
                    "neighborDevice": "HP830_LSW",
                    "neighborPort": "GigabitEthernet1/0/12",
                    "port": "Ethernet47"
                    },
                    {
                    "ttl": 120,
                    "neighborDevice": "HP_5500EI",
                    "neighborPort": "GigabitEthernet2/0/22",
                    "port": "Ethernet48"
                    },
                    {
                    "ttl": 120,
                    "neighborDevice": "HP_5500EI",
                    "neighborPort": "GigabitEthernet1/0/24",
                    "port": "Management1"
                    }
                ],
                "tablesDeletes": 0,
                "tablesDrops": 0
                }
            ],
            "id": "EapiExplorer-1"
            }
```

I want to send the content of a list to a single string.

Comment: FYI, that is a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: what is your expected output? thanks.

Comment: How did you include that dictionary in your question, if you're unable to print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **json** module contains a method called 'dumps' which can take in your dictionary and return a string.

```
import json
my_string = json.dumps(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods here you could use. The first is to generically pretty-print:

```
import pprint
...
pprint.pprint(output_list)
```

The second is to output in `json` format, since your `output_list` looks like it belongs that way:

```
import json
...
print(json.dumps(output_list))
```